# Why the reopen queue takes a long time to clear?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

I've noticed that the reopen queue typically takes longer to clear than other review tasks. Because of that, this queue often accumulates more questions to be reviewed than others (see the figure below).

What could be the likely reason for that?

[image: screenshot of the review queues showing the re-open queue marked with a red dot.]

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, it seems to be stuck in this state for a couple of days now

Comment: @Sursula Right now we have two questions pending votes to be reopen or kept closed.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338688/383809

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it takes time to check the original question, the modifications to it, the discussion around it, and the original reasons put forward for closing.

Reviewers may find the reopen queue to be the most demanding and skip reopen votes more often due to the difficulties in figuring out the proper decision.

Comment: I understand, so less people are eager to review them.

Comment: @TheDoctor I am not sure if they are necessarily less eager, I often find that I am unable to come to a satisfactory decision and skip the "reopen" cue much more often than any other review cue. I find it is the most difficult of the cues. Also because sometimes there is some crazy editing going on with the "reopen" questions that doesn't make it any easier.